# Swagger UI with Java9 (spring boot 2.0)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui, java-9, swagger-2.0

I'm trying to make the swagger UI work with my service. I'm using spring boot 2.0 and Java 9. The following dependencies are added for swagger

```
compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.8.0')
compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.8.0')
```

The swagger is configured as it should

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Compiles well but when I starting up the application with the BootRun command it fails due:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xmlModelPlugin': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [springfox.documentation.schema.XmlModelPlugin] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4f8e5cde]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

What could be the problem? Not compatible with Java9? Then can I make it work somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's incompatibility with java 9.

I think you have three options:

- add explicit dependency to xml apis like `compile('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0')`
- update springfox version to [2.9.0](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2226)
- add `--add-modules java.xml.bind` to jvm startup params (this is more just a workaround instead of a fix, in comparison to other options, since [this module will be removed in the later versions of java](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320))

Further reading on Spring Boot and java 9: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-with-Java-9-and-above

Comment: As per the JDK 9 docs, `--add-modules java.xml.bind` is a temporary workaround as the java.xml.bind is deprecated in Java SE for removal. It has already been dropped in JDK 11 EA builds, see JEP 320 for all the details. The best option is to move to the standalone version of JAXB, the API and implementation can be downloaded from Maven Central.

Comment: @AlanBateman thanks for the comment. Updated answer based on that

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about this very specific error, but in general Swagger 2.9.x seems to have some incompatibility with SpringBoot 2.0.x

Some documented issues:
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1773 (main one)
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2501

There is a 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT version which might be more stable with this Spring Boot version.

Answer (score 1):

version 2.9.0 could not be found in maven central. Available versions are `2.9.1` and `2.9.2`

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2

As suggested by @eis after upgrade from `2.8.0` to `2.9.2` fixed the issue for me